# Mongodb / Mongoose: Can I sort a parent query by a populated child document's created date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB / Mongoose query like so:

```
WineUniversal.find(query)
.populate([{
    path: 'userWines',
    model: 'Wine',
    match: {scoreTotal: {$gte: 50} }
}])
.sort({'userWines[0].created': -1 }) // Can something like this be done?
.limit(500)
.skip(0)
.exec(function() {...})
```

Is it possible to change the query where the `.sort()` function is based on the `created' date property of the populated userWines documents?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more precise about the [SOMETHING HERE ...]? Based on your example it would be a value of either 1 or -1 so the "joined" document would specify the sort direction or what do you imagine?

Comment: Made an edit to the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such functionality is built into mongoose populate.

You can easily achieve something like in 3.4.

Similar concept as  to populate but all the heavy lifting is done in single server call through aggregation framework.

`$lookup` stage is used to pull data from wines collection based on matching userWines array followed by `$unwind` and `$match` to provide query criteria for matching wines.

`$group` stage to push all the wines back into array.

`$sort` stage to sort the input documents based on the max created date from array of wines.

```
WineUniversal.aggregate([
{"$match":query}, 
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"wines", // name of the collection, not model or schema name
  "localField":"userWines",
  "foreignField":"_id",
  "as":"userWines"
}},
{"$unwind":"$userWines"},
{"$match":{"userWines.scoreTotal":{"$gte":50}}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id",
  "userWines":{"$push":"$userWines"}
}},
{"$sort":{"userWines.created":-1}},
{"$limit":500},
{"$skip":0}]).exec(function() {...})
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Are you available for hire to help me form the query? (paypal / skype ??)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm not at this time.

Comment: Cool. Thx for you help.

Comment: One follow-up clarification: in the `$group` stage of the aggregation, if I just need the `$userWines` object and not pushing it to an array, what operator can I use instead of `$push` ?

Comment: Try $first or $last operator but will require some kind of sort before to make sense.

Comment: Got it working. Just needed to add the other properties in the `$group` stage and everything worked perfectly. Thank you again!! :)